# How use parameter by sshPublisher in pipeline of Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

in pipeline, the g_VersionNum has defined, the following method:

```
sshPublisher(publishers: [sshPublisherDesc(configName: 'VersionServer', transfers: [sshTransfer(excludes: '', execCommand: 'pwd;echo $${g_VersionNum}', execTimeout: 120000, flatten: false, makeEmptyDirs: false, noDefaultExcludes: false, patternSeparator: '[, ]+', remoteDirectory: 'alpha/${g_VersionNum}', remoteDirectorySDF: false, removePrefix: 'target', sourceFiles: 'target/abc-${g_VersionNum}.tar.gz')], usePromotionTimestamp: false, useWorkspaceInPromotion: false, verbose: false)])
```

${g_VersionNum} is blank in runtime.

When i use 20180327 instead of ${g_VersionNum}:

```
sshPublisher(publishers: [sshPublisherDesc(configName: 'VersionServer', transfers: [sshTransfer(excludes: '', execCommand: '', execTimeout: 120000, flatten: false, makeEmptyDirs: false, noDefaultExcludes: false, patternSeparator: '[, ]+', remoteDirectory: 'f_alpha/20180327', remoteDirectorySDF: false, removePrefix: 'target', sourceFiles: 'target/abc-20180327.tar.gz')], usePromotionTimestamp: false, useWorkspaceInPromotion: false, verbose: false)])
```

The script runs correctly.


I has tried with escape as: \${g_VersionNum}, $${g_VersionNum}, they still don't work.

I has confirmed the parameter definition, in the same steps:

```
sh 'echo ${g_VersionNum}'
```

The value can be show correctly.
And i has tested for using the JENKINS enviroment variable, they are valid, just i defines in pipeline is invalid:

```
  environment {
    g_VersionNum = VersionNumber(versionNumberString: '${BUILD_YEAR}${BUILD_MONTH,XX}${BUILD_DAY,XX}', skipFailedBuilds: true, worstResultForIncrement: 'SUCCESS')
  }
```

Who knowns how to use the parameter in sshPublisher plugin? thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to change ' with " , otherwise groovy will not execute and get the value of the g_VersionNum

Comment: This resolve my question, but i have one doubt, as my description, when i use: sh 'echo ${g_VersionNum}', why the groovy execute the single quote?

Comment: because in that case it is not groovy executes , but sh (shell) executes the ommand ;) that's why you have to understand the difference the commands that are executed by groovy itself and the commands that jenkins will pass to other executors (sh, mvn, gradle etc etc )

Answer (score 1):

You should use " " not ' ',
I tested using ' ' and it didn't work:

```
sshPublisher(publishers: [sshPublisherDesc(configName: 'test', transfers: [sshTransfer(cleanRemote: false, excludes: '', execCommand: '$DEPLOY_COMMAND', execTimeout: 120000, flatten: false, makeEmptyDirs: false, noDefaultExcludes: false, patternSeparator: '[, ]+', remoteDirectory: '', remoteDirectorySDF: false, removePrefix: '$SUB_MODULE/target', sourceFiles: '$SUB_MODULE/target/*.jar')], usePromotionTimestamp: false, useWorkspaceInPromotion: false, verbose: false)])
```

But using " " can work:

```
sshPublisher(publishers: [sshPublisherDesc(configName: 'test', transfers: [sshTransfer(cleanRemote: false, excludes: '', execCommand: "$DEPLOY_COMMAND", execTimeout: 120000, flatten: false, makeEmptyDirs: false, noDefaultExcludes: false, patternSeparator: '[, ]+', remoteDirectory: '', remoteDirectorySDF: false, removePrefix: "$SUB_MODULE/target", sourceFiles: "$SUB_MODULE/target/*.jar")], usePromotionTimestamp: false, useWorkspaceInPromotion: false, verbose: false)])
```